# Add and use behaviours of agent with saving a flexibility

Tags: c#, system, behavior, agents, multi-agent

There are many behaviours in my agent, whose number and consist isn't known beforehand. Behaviour is an algorithm of action in response of some events in system or in agent itself. 
I would wanted to do something like that:

```
public abstract class AbstractBehaviour 
{        
    ... // etc
    public abstract void Do(); 
}
class ConcreteBehaviour1 : AbstractBehaviour 
{   ...//fields etc   
    public void Do() { ... }  
} 
class ConcreteBehaviour2 : AbstractBehaviour
{  
    ...//fields etc   
    public void Do() { ... } 
}
public class Agent : IAgent
{
    private Dictionary<String, AbstractBehaviour> Behaviours;
    private Type1 Field1;
    private Type2 Firld2;
    public void Algorithm( ... )
    {
        Behaviours[NeccessaryBehaviour1].Do();
        Agent.Filed1 = Behaviours[NeccessaryBehaviour1].GetData();
        Behaviours[NeccessaryBehaviour111].Do();
        Agent.Filed2 = Behaviours[NeccessaryBehaviour111].GetData();
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is I cant get neccessary data from behaviours. Could you tell what mechanism can be used for saving flexibility and getting neccessary data at once?
I  want to save a probability of adding functionality to my agents.

Comment: `AbstractBehaviour` doesn't define `GetData` and when it does, it'll need to be either `Type1` or `Type2`, not both. You are trying to use polymorphism when your types and data are not polymorphic by the looks of it.

Comment: @DavidArno Its the other part of the main problem. I should wotk with different types.

Comment: You can use lots of getters. Usually the behavior knows which agent it belongs to. So, it can get data from its agent.

Comment: @darlinton, but agents belongs to IAgent and in that case i can't look into them

Comment: Behaviours belong to Agents. You can inform the Agent object that owns the behaviour on the behaviours instantiation. Change the behaviour constructor to receive the agent owner. I recomend you to check the Jade implementation: http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/core/behaviours/Behaviour.html